# CentOS sending out NTP packets while NTP service is stopped

Tags: centos, ntpd

NTP service is stopped, still my CentOS machine is sending out NTP packets to a NTP server:

[image: image attached for reference]

```
# service ntpd status
ntpd is stopped
```

Comment: What version of CentOS is this? Your screenshot is from an Ubuntu system. (And you should copy and paste text and avoid screenshots whenever possible.)

Comment: It also doesn't have to be `ntpd`, could always be `ntpdate` or another ntp client or something similar.

Comment: Version is CentOS release 6.7 (Final).

Comment: # ntpdate -d
13 Sep 18:51:43 ntpdate[13438]: ntpdate 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Mon Jan 25 14:08:28 UTC 2016 (1)
13 Sep 18:51:43 ntpdate[13438]: no servers can be used, exiting

Comment: @Lenniey Yes its ntpdate which is generating traffic but i was unable to find from which application or location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more troubleshooting, i found out that one crontab is running with ntpdate which is generating huge ntp traffic:

*/05 * * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate -u ntp-server-ip

Answer (score 1):

In addition to traditional ntpd your system may have an alternative tool installed, configured and running that syncs your clock using the NTP protocol.

"[chrony](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chrony)"  comes to mind but most likely **systemd is synching your clock with ntp**, check with

```
[sudo] timedatectl status
```

and if that is the case expect an output like the following :

> ```
>       Local time: Fri 2019-09-13 13:29:18 CEST
>   Universal time: Fri 2019-09-13 11:29:18 UTC
>         RTC time: Fri 2019-09-13 11:29:18
>        Time zone: Europe/Amsterdam (CEST, +0200)
>      NTP enabled: yes
> NTP synchronized: yes
>  RTC in local TZ: no
>       DST active: yes
>  Last DST change: DST began at
>                   Sun 2019-03-31 01:59:59 CET
>                   Sun 2019-03-31 03:00:00 CEST
>  Next DST change: DST ends (the clock jumps one hour backwards) at
>                   Sun 2019-10-27 02:59:59 CEST
>                   Sun 2019-10-27 02:00:00 CET
> ```

See

- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-timesyncd.service.html
- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timedatectl.html

Comment: # timedatectl status
-bash: timedatectl: command not found

Comment: Version is CentOS release 6.7